# Как правильно делать обработку исключений PrintStream, чтобы созданным объектом можно было пользоваться за пределами try

Tags: java, исключения

Я пытался добиться истины методом тыка, но не получилось, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. Как обработать исключение FileNotFoundException (да и в целом любое исключение), чтобы try распространялся только на создание объектов и при этом я мог пользоваться созданными объектами за пределами try. Один из вариантов, который я придумал представлен ниже, но в параметрах методов createOutDataForAdmin и createOutDataForAdmin объекты outAdmin и outComputer класса PrintStream якобы не инициализированы.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream outAdmin,outComputer;
        Scanner scan;
        try {
            outAdmin = new PrintStream("Out data for admin.txt");
            outComputer = new PrintStream("Out data for compute.txt");
            scan = new Scanner(new File("Out data for admin.txt"));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException exception){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        User arrayUsers[]=new User[1];

        createOutDataForAdmin(arrayUsers,outAdmin);
        createOutDataForComputer(arrayUsers,outComputer);

    }
```

Был еще такой вариант. Код все тот же только изменен блок try catch. Все та же проблема за пределами try не могу пользоваться созданными объектами.

```
try {
            PrintStream outAdmin = new PrintStream("Out data for admin.txt");
            PrintStream outComputer = new PrintStream("Out data for compute.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Out data for admin.txt"));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException exception){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
```

И третий вариант, я весь код запихнул в try. Его я не вижу смысла иллюстрировать. Мне кажется, это так не должно выглядеть, хотя в этом случае все работало как надо.
Если что-то напутал в терминах, прощу критиковать)

Comment: на самом деле вам это делать не нужно. ваш метод создал 2 экземпляра Scanner и еще 2 PrintStream и ни одним из них не воспользовался. Привет вам от паттерна Creator (GRASP) ровно как и от SOLID.  вывод простой: у вас не получается это сделать потому, что вы пытаетесь прикрутить очевидный костыль) не то, чтобы это невозможно, вам даже уже показали как, проинициализировав переменные null, но это порождает больше проблем, чем решает. давайте подойдем к проблеме с другой стороны: опишите что вы хотите сделать, а потом мы попробуем найти нормальное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй в таком виде:

```
 public class main {
        public static void main(String args[]){
                Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
                PrintStream outAdmin=null;
                PrintStream  outComputer=null;
                Scanner scan;
            try {
                outAdmin = new PrintStream("Out data for admin.txt");
                outComputer = new PrintStream("Out data for compute.txt");
                scan = new Scanner(new File("Out data for admin.txt"));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException exception){
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }
    
            User arrayUsers[]=new User[1];
    
            createOutDataForAdmin(arrayUsers,outAdmin);
            createOutDataForComputer(arrayUsers,outComputer);
    
        }
```